# Stack every two elements of the third dimension in a numpy 3d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of shape (294, 62, 350). Along the third dimension (the 350), I need to combine every two columns into one longer one which would result in an array of shape (294, 124, 175). For example if I have this array:

```
a_3d_array = np.array([[[1, 2, 3, 6, 1, 2], [3, 4, 3, 6, 1, 4]],
                      [[5, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2], [2, 9, 4, 3, 2, 7]]])
```

The expected output would be:

```
expected_output = np.array([[[5, 2, 4], [2, 4, 2], [ 2, 1, 2], [9, 3, 7]],
                          [[1, 3, 1], [3, 3, 1], [2, 6, 2], [4, 6, 4]]])
```

Sorry as I'm new to python and I don't have a clue how to approach this and thus I don't have a "my own attempt" to include here.

Answer (score 1):

```
a_3d_array = np.array([[[1, 2, 3, 6, 1, 2], [3, 4, 3, 6, 1, 4]],
                     [[5, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2], [2, 9, 4, 3, 2, 7]]])
output = np.hstack([a_3d_array[:, :, ::2], a_3d_array[:, :, 1::2]])
```

To combine every N-th column:

```
N = 3
output = np.hstack([an_array[:, :, idx::N] for idx in range(N)])
```

Comment: hey thanks! This seems to work, If you want to combine every 3rd column instead of every second would the solution then be: `output = np.hstack([a_3d_array[:, :, ::3], a_3d_array[:, :, 1::3]])`?

Comment: @stevezissou not at all. I edited answer, hope this is what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can `reshape` and reverse the first dimension:

```
a_3d_array.reshape((2,4,3), order='F')[::-1]
```

If you don't know the shape:

```
x,y,z = a_3d_array.shape
a_3d_array.reshape((x,y*2,-1), order='F')[::-1]
```

output:

```
array([[[5, 2, 4],
        [2, 4, 2],
        [2, 1, 2],
        [9, 3, 7]],

       [[1, 3, 1],
        [3, 3, 1],
        [2, 6, 2],
        [4, 6, 4]]])
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to generalize to the real life case where there are more dimensions. For example, if I apply your solution to: `a_3d_array = np.array([[[1, 2, 3, 6, 1, 2], [3, 4, 3, 6, 1, 4]],
                       [[24, 22, 31, 26, 11, 22], [23, 24, 23, 26, 21, 24]],
                      [[5, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2], [2, 9, 4, 3, 2, 7]]])` Then I get an error...

Comment: @steve you didn't mention generalization to a greater number of dimensions, although this is perfectly doable. NB
 downvoting the answer seems unfair given the little description you gave... Btw, the other answer also doesn't generalize to an arbitrary step size (mine does).

Comment: And my answer **does work** on the example provided as comment… you just need to use the second code I gave…

Comment: ok, looks good, I'll upvote it when I can. Thanks for your help.